# KMeans - running into OSError: image not already loaded

Tags: python, dataframe, k-means

I am running a simple code for KMeans:

```
# Scaling the data set before clustering
scaler = StandardScaler()
subset = df[num_col].copy()
subset_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(subset)

subset_scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(subset_scaled, columns=subset.columns)

clusters = range(1, 9)
meanDistortions = []

for k in clusters:
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    model.fit(subset_scaled_df)
    prediction = model.predict(subset_scaled_df)
    distortion = (
        sum(
            np.min(cdist(subset_scaled_df, model.cluster_centers_, "euclidean"), axis=1)
        )
        / subset_scaled_df.shape[0]
    )

    meanDistortions.append(distortion)

    print("Number of Clusters:", k, "\tAverage Distortion:", distortion)

plt.plot(clusters, meanDistortions, "bx-")
plt.xlabel("k")
plt.ylabel("Average Distortion")
plt.title("Selecting k with the Elbow Method", fontsize=20)
```

Running into the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-173-4b988580ff32> in <module>
     11 for k in clusters:
     12     model = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
---> 13     model.fit(subset_scaled_df)
     14     prediction = model.predict(subset_scaled_df)
     15     distortion = (

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1006         if self._algorithm == "full":
   1007             kmeans_single = _kmeans_single_lloyd
-> 1008             self._check_mkl_vcomp(X, X.shape[0])
   1009         else:
   1010             kmeans_single = _kmeans_single_elkan

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in _check_mkl_vcomp(self, X, n_samples)
    872         active_threads = int(np.ceil(n_samples / CHUNK_SIZE))
    873         if active_threads < self._n_threads:
--> 874             modules = threadpool_info()
    875             has_vcomp = "vcomp" in [module["prefix"] for module in modules]
    876             has_mkl = ("mkl", "intel") in [

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py in threadpool_info()
    122     In addition, each module may contain internal_api specific entries.
    123     """
--> 124     return _ThreadpoolInfo(user_api=_ALL_USER_APIS).todicts()
    125 
    126 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    338 
    339             self.modules = []
--> 340             self._load_modules()
    341             self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py in _load_modules(self)
    369         """Loop through loaded libraries and store supported ones"""
    370         if sys.platform == "darwin":
--> 371             self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372         elif sys.platform == "win32":
    373             self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py in _find_modules_with_dyld(self)
    426 
    427             # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 428             self._make_module_from_path(filepath)
    429 
    430     def _find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py in _make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513             if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514                 module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515                 module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516                 self.modules.append(module)
    517 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    603         self.user_api = user_api
    604         self.internal_api = internal_api
--> 605         self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
    606         self.version = self.get_version()
    607         self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()

/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    372 
    373         if handle is None:
--> 374             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    375         else:
    376             self._handle = handle

OSError: image not already loaded
```

However, if I replace the above code with the following, it works fine:

```
clusters = range(1, 9)
meanDistortions = []

for k in clusters:
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=8)
```

Instead of passing "k" into KMeans(n_clusters= ), if I pass an integer it works fine. Not able to understand what is going wrong, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your sklearn package:
`pip install -U sklearn`

Answer (score 0):

I assume it throws the error for k=1, and works for k > 1. This would also explain your working modification. So you could do `range(2, 9)` as a quick fix. I'm observing the same in my most recent sklean environment (0.24.2).